# Move cloned ssd windows 10 to new hardware acquire a new license and keep old for old hardware

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, drivers

i have an i5 windows 10 with 2 SSD and this is my old hardware I want to move to new hardware with i7 my plan is to pick the one SSD which is a clone with windows 10, and boot to a new hardware. My question is if Microsoft asks for new license on new hardware and if i acquire can i keep the old license for my old hardware or it will be deleted by the new one?

My license key is Retail thanks to @ChanganAuto for his help

Comment: OEM licenses are supposed to be tied to a specific hardware therefore can't be transferred to a different one. So, yes, if you have an OEM license that license will remain in the old hardware and regardless of how many time you reinstall Windows 10 it should automatically activate. The license won't be transferred to the new hardware even if you use a clone and you'll need a new license.

Comment: @ChanganAuto so i can have a new license in the new hardware and keep the old license for the old hardware without any issues? boot my already installed windows 10 on the new machine and buy a new license. right?

Comment: Again, if the original license is OEM you *must* keep it in the old hardware.

Comment: @ChanganAuto i check my licence key with this cmd command
 "Slmgr –dli" and says it retail no OEM so do i have any chances?

Answer (score 0):

If the BIOS Chip on your new hardware contains an OEM license you will be able to query for its unique Win10 Product Key using the following command inside CMD:

```
wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

After this, you simply copy/paste the product key into the Windows 10 Activation screen by selecting "Change Product Key".